# Number to decimal sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Can't figure out how to format my gpa field properly:

```
select y.id,
       max(case when y.r = 1 then y.gpa_c end) gpa
  from table y
```

current output:

```
 ID |   GPA
----+------
392 |     0  
399 | 3.234
400 |     4
401 |   3.6
```

I've tried `cast()`, `convert()`, `decimal()`, `to_char()` with `2, 3`

I'd like for everything be formatted `0.000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `to_char()`:

```
TO_CHAR(column, '0d9999')
```

In your query:

```
select y.id,
       TO_CHAR(max(case when y.r = 1 then y.gpa_c end), '0d9999') gpa
  from table y
```

Obligatory Note:  Best reserved for display purposes, most numbers should not be stored as strings.

Updated to correctly show leading zero for `0` gpa.

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/568d6/4/0)

Comment: Quotes are what got me. Thanks.

Comment: is there a way to retain the number type while using these new found decimals?

Comment: Nope, this changes it to a string.  Also it doesn't seem to work right for 0

Comment: You can change it back to number type using `TO_NUMBER`.